# Limit law question

Tags: calculus, limits

Given 
$$\lim_{x \to -1} (\frac{f(x)+2}{x+1} - \frac{x}{x^2-1})=4,$$
find, using limit laws, the limit
$$\lim_{x \to -1} f(x).$$

Now, I know the $Quotient$ $Rule$ 
$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{L}{M}, $$
where $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L,\space \lim_{x \to c}g(x)=M ,\space  m \neq 0$.
But here $$\lim_{x \to -1} (x+1)=0.$$
What should I do?

Comment: Just write everything above the same denominator inside the limit and note that if f(x) doesn't tend to a certain limit the fraction blows up.
What you need is the product rule not the quotient rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$4 = \lim\limits_{x \to -1} \left(\frac{f(x)+2}{x+1} - \frac{x}{x^2-1}\right)=\lim\limits_{x \to -1} \frac{1}{x+1}\left(f(x)+2 - \frac{x}{x-1}\right),$$ we must have $$\lim\limits_{x \to -1} \left(f(x)+2 - \frac{x}{x-1}\right) = 0,$$ otherwise the aforementioned limit would not exist. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let the expression under limit be $g(x) $ so that $g(x) \to 4$ as $x\to - 1$ and $$f(x) =(x+1)g(x) +\frac{x} {x-1}-2$$ and taking limits as $x\to - 1$ we get $$\lim_{x\to - 1}f(x)=0\cdot 4+\frac{1}{2}-2=-\frac{3}{2}$$ **Note** that the answer is independent of the given limit $4$.

Comment: Paramand.Very nice.